# Palindrome vs Level of Palindrome

Tags: number-theory, palindrome

The palindrome, example: $131$, $82728$, $55655$.

But from the palindrome maker algorithm
say:

If $17$ isn't palindrome you must additive by reverse of them

$33$ is say $P(1)$ palindrome

$38$ is say $P(2)$ semipalindrome of level $1$

Because:

$38+83=121$

$182$ is say $P(5)$ semipalindrome of level $4$

Because:

$182+281=463$

$463+364=827$

$827+728=1555$

$1555+5551=6666$

> So the question is:
>
> How many semipalindrome of level $1$ between $1-1000$ are?

Comment: Well, if there are no carries involved in the addition then you always get a palindrome on one iteration, as in $134+431=565$. That gives you a lot of them, but not all (as your $38+83$ example shows).  I wouldn't think it would be too hard to count those examples as well...after all they must begin and end in $1$ after the sum.

Comment: Is $2$ a semipalindrome because $2+2=4$ and $4$ is a palindrome?  How about $22$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with a two digit number $ab$ you get a palindrome in two cases:

- if $a+b \lt 10$ there will be no carry so you get $11(a+b)$
- if you carry $1$ and the ones digit is $1$, so when $a+b=11$

If you start with a three digit number $abc$ you get a palindrome:

- if there are no carries at all
- if $a+c =11$ so the ones digit of the sum is $1$ and there is a carry, then $2b+1$ does not carry and matches the $1$ that $a+c$ gives in the hundreds, so $b=0$
- if $a+c=11$ and $2b+1$ does carry there will be a $2$ in the hundreds, which $2b+1$ cannot match.  This does not work.